# Ajax Request always timing out

Tags: node.js, ajax

I am making a food ordering website in which i have to send all the order details from ejs page to the node backend. My code is shown below. The problem i am having with this is that the ajax request is always timing out irrespective of the timeout time being 10 seconds to one minute(no data is being transferred and its timing out at the given time).

```
$.ajax({url:"/checkout",
        timeout:10000,
         type:"POST",
       data:{
        restro:b,
         custo:a,
         loc:c,
        bill:bill,
        order:arr,
        slot:e,
       pay:f, 
        room:g},
       success:(result)=>{
        console.log(result+" its here");
    },
     error:(x,y,error)=>{console.log(error)}});
```

the nodejs code working in the backend is:-

```
app.post("/checkout",isLoggedIn,(req,res)=>{

    for(var i=0;i<req.body.order.length;i++){
      if(req.body.order[i].itname=="nullified")
      req.body.order.splice(i,1);
      i=0;
    }

   var orderpp={
     restroname:req.body.restro,
     cusname:req.body.custo,
     deliveryadd:req.body.loc,
     bill:req.body.bill,
     items:req.body.order,
     deliveryslot:req.body.slot,
     payment:req.body.pay,
     roomdet:req.body.room
   };

   console.log(orderpp.items);

   Order.create(orderpp,(err,neworder)=>{
     if (err) {
       req.flash("error",err.message);
       res.redirect("/index");
     } else {

       console.log(neworder);

     }
   })
  })
```

Expected output is a new record to be created and displayed in the server console but the ajax request is timing out. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see a timeout on client side ?

If so, I don't see a res.send(status_code, res_object) or res.json(res_object) in case order creation was a success, it is essential to send back a response and mark request as completed.